# Making Sip call in android

Tags: android, sip, sip-server, imsdroid

I am using ngn stack library to make sip calls.

If I test on local server when I am connected to WI-FI, it works very fine with audio as well as video. But, on original server I am unable to make call, even there is no request being hit on server side. If I use other applications like 'ZOIPER' it works also fine.

Following error occurs when I click call button after registering both clients. below is the logcat output for the error

```
12-14 10:35:54.146: D/org.doubango.ngn.services.impl.NgnSipService(4383): OnDialogEvent (Transport error,3)
12-14 10:35:54.146: D/org.doubango.ngn.sip.NgnAVSession(4383): setState(TERMINATED)
12-14 10:35:54.147: D/dalvikvm(4383): create interp thread : stack size=128KB
12-14 10:35:54.149: D/org.doubango.ngn.media.NgnProxyAudioProducer(4383): stopCallback

please help me out.
```

Comment: do you register your sip account ? Check if credentials are correct

Comment: yes everything is fine.even i am able to make call with local server.

Comment: what errors do you receive ?

Comment: no error in log,but it is transport error i can find while using IMSDROID

Comment: even i am able to receive incoming calls,but problem occurs with outgoing calls

Comment: is there something wrong with header???

Comment: what transport error do you get ?

Comment: i really dont know ,i cant find it in the log,this kind of error is being displayed on the screen in IMSDROID application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes i found the solution it was somethig NATT issue.
just write code for USE STUN for SIP
during configuration setting by writing this code.

```
ngnConfigService.putBoolean(
                NgnConfigurationEntry.NATT_USE_STUN_FOR_SIP, true, true);
```

Now it's working fine